# Why does the upload of an image work only for the first form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a page with multiple items and a form for each item which allow users to update these items.

Each item's form contain an image file input and other inputs.

When I update an item by updating only the other inputs, it work well, but when I try to update the image of an item, it work only on the first item, otherwise it does nothing.

**Here is the part of the html form with the input file:**

```
<div id="modifier_emlement_{{$elem->id}}">
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/Clients/{{$client->nom}}/Batiments/{{$batiment->id}}/Consulter/Element/{{$elem->id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <div class="un_element col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">
                <label for="image_elem"> 
                    <img class="rounded" style="max-width: 100%; border-radius: 5px;" src="{{$elem->lien_photo}}" alt="image de l'element">
                </label>
                <input type="file" id="image_elem" name="image_elem" accept="image/*" class="form-control" style="display:none;">
            </div>
```

**Here the part of the html form with the submit button:**

```
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id_batiment" name="id_batiment" value="{{$batiment->id}}">
                    <input type="hidden" id="groupe" name="groupe" value="{{$groupe}}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Enregistrer </button>
                </div>
        </form>
```

**Here is the function called inside my controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $client, $id_bat, $id)
    {

        dd($request->file('image_elem'));
        $request->validate([
            'image_elem' => 'mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:5048'
        ]);
        
        if($request->hasFile('image_elem')){ //(isset($request->image_elem)){
            $newImageName =time().'-elem'. $id.'.'. $request->image_elem->extension();
        
            $request->image_elem->move(public_path('images'), $newImageName);

            $lien = '/images/'.$newImageName;
        }else{
            $lien ="/img/placeholder-image.jpg";
        }
        

        $element = elements::where('id', $id)
                ->update([
                    'id_batiment' => $request->input('id_batiment'),
                    'lien_photo' => $lien,
                    'groupe' => $request->input('groupe'),
                    'intitule' => $request->input('intitule'),
                    'description' => $request->input('description'),
                    'etat' => $request->input('note_etat'),
                    'obsolescence' => $request->input('note_obsolescence'),
                    'quantite' => $request->input('quantite'),
                    'unite' => $request->input('unite'),
                    'date_element' => $request->input('date_element')
            ]);
            $batiment = batiments::find($id_bat)->first();
            $leclient = entreprises::where('nom',$client)->first();
            
            return redirect('/Clients/'.$leclient->nom.'/Batiments/'.$id_bat.'/Consulter')->with('client', $leclient, 'batiment', $batiment);
    }
```

And just in case it may help, here is how I generate multiple items in my page:

```
  @forelse($leselements as $elem)
            <div class="row espace-bas">
                @include('layouts.element')
            </div>
            @endif
  @empty

  @endforelse
```

As you can see in the controller function, I did try to DD the image input and had an image only when updating the first item, otherwise it returned null.

After looking for answers on other threads I tried to change the variables upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in my php.ini in order to allows upload of over 500MO, but it didn't help.

I also tried to put a unique id on the input file but than the DD doesn't return any file (even for the first form)
[dd with unique id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzNWU.png)

Comment: you have multiple forms and each form has a submit button ?

Comment: @N69S yes, one submit button inside each form

Answer (score 1):

I found why it didn't work. The label did not reference a unique id.
So after this:

```
<label for="image_elem"> 
                <img class="rounded" style="max-width: 100%; border-radius: 5px;" src="{{$elem->lien_photo}}" alt="image de l'element">
            </label>
            <input type="file" id="image_elem" name="image_elem" accept="image/
```

I tried this:

```
<label for="image_elem"> 
                <img class="rounded" style="max-width: 100%; border-radius: 5px;" src="{{$elem->lien_photo}}" alt="image de l'element">
            </label>
            <input type="file" id="image_elem{{$elem->id}}" name="image_elem" accept="image/
```

But it didn’t work since the id was not the same.
So here is the answer:

```
<label for="image_elem{{$elem->id}}"> 
                <img class="rounded" style="max-width: 100%; border-radius: 5px;" src="{{$elem->lien_photo}}" alt="image de l'element">
            </label>
            <input type="file" id="image_elem{{$elem->id}}" name="image_elem" accept="image/
```